# Reloading asp.net core swagger ui without restarting the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to create a service to show multiple Swagger documentations from different microservices. I am using Asp.NET Core with the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package. I can very easily configure multiple endpoints on startup with the following lines.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("url1", "Name 1");
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("url2", "Name 2");
    });
```

My problem is that I want the ability to dynamically edit the list of endpoints without the need to restart the service. Is there any way to achieve this with the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` or with anything else?

Comment: Where do you want to edit the list of endpoints? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784268/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-add-swaggerendpoints-for-swaggerui)

Comment: Fair suggestion I will try it. I tought that if you configure it once, it will load every resource on startup, and if I change the options after, then it has no effect.